# How to make a list of students who have passed all the exams in the file

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have file with lines like:

```
 1. 'abc0123,spja,40'
 2. 'sed0898,spja,15'
 3. 'sed0898,spja,10'

 4. 'abc0123,udbs,10'
 5. 'bem0334,dim,18'
 6. 'bem0334,dim,0'
 7. 'bem0334,spja,30'
```

etc. first word before comma means student login, second mean subject of exam and third means points for exam. One row represents one attempt on exam. I need return only students who passed on exams to which they tried. Doesn't matter on order by lines. In case above passed students bem0334 and sed0898. For passing student must have 15 and more points. So i started with saving lines into list of strings but i don't know how to test if students has passed on all his exams. `

```
def vrat_uspesne(soubor_vysledky):
    f = open(soubor_vysledky, "r")
    studens = []
    exams = []
    tmp = ""
    for line in f:
        spliter = line.split(',')
        exams.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
        student.append(spliter[0])
    student = set(student)
    student = list(student)
return student
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a typo in that code snippet (student vs students).
The general approach I would suggest is to map lines to data structs, then group the data by student login using a dictionary.

Comment: So i need dictionary with key = studentLogin, but what should be value?

Comment: a set of the structs